# How to use Flask url_for in a CSS file?

Tags: html, css, flask, jinja2

I'm using Flask with HTML and CSS. When this is possible:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/planets.jpeg' ) }}">
```

What do I have to write here to address the same image?

```
.bgimg-1 { background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/J9QOB6hSI-c/maxresdefault.jpg'); }
```

The solution should look similar to this:

```
.bgimg-1 { background-image: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='images/planets.jpeg' ) }}'); }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't use Jinja directly in the CSS file since you normally don't render it as a template, but there is 3 alternate way to achieve your need:

### Method 1

Use correct relative path in your CSS file:

```
background: url("/static/images/bg.jpg") no-repeat 0px 0px;
```

### Method 2

Put your `background` line into the template:

```
<style>
    background: url("{{ url_for('static',filename='images/bg.jpg') }}") no-repeat 0px 0px;
</style>
```

### Method 3

Define a CSS variable in your template:

```
<style>
    :root {
        --background-url: {{ url_for('static', filename='images/bg.jpg') }}
    }
</style>
```

Then use it in your CSS file:

```
background: url("var(--background-url)") no-repeat 0px 0px;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are serving css statically, via `/static/css/style.css`. When you do this, then Flask does not use Jinja to parse the CSS file as though it were a template.

If, however, you had a route (eg `@app.route('/css/<file>')`) then you could use the render_template() method to render your CSS file as though it were a jinja template, which would then parse the jinja directives (such as `{{url_for()}}`)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply refer to the generated URL in your `url_for` function.

As an example:

```
.bgimg-1 {
   background-image: url('/static/images/planets.jpeg');
   min-height: 100%;
}
```

Also, please note that the CSS itself can be referenced with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/planets.css') }}">
```

**UPDATE:**

Alternatively, you can embed your Jinja2 in the style attribute. For example:

```
<body style="background-image: url({{ url_for('static', filename='images/planets.jpeg') }});">
<!-- HTML TEMPLATE CODE -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation points to comment on [Grey Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5511849/grey-li) answer.   Method 3 is good - modified to make it work

HTML template

```
<style>
:root {
    --background-url: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='img/lightning.jpg', _external=True) }}');
}
</style>
```

CSS

```
background: var(--default-bg-color) var(--background-url);
```

Answer (score 1):

My requirement was to add a font file in a CSS file.
The static folder structure I used was like:

```
static 
├── css
|   ├── main.css
├── fonts
|   ├── NotoSans-Regular.ttf
├── js
|   ├── index.js
```

If I used Flask's url_for() function in the main.css file as follows

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'NotoSans';
  src: url("{{url_for('static', filename='fonts/NotoSans-Regular.ttf')}}");
}
```

The request was being sent to

> *http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/css/static/fonts/NotoSans-Regular.ttf*
>
> (Assuming that the server was running on PORT 5000)

So, I replaced it with the following and it worked fine.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'NotoSans';
  src: url("/static/fonts/NotoSans-Regular.ttf");
}
```